# Get user followers information along with count of user followers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple table below, User `2 & 3` are following user `1` , user `3` is following user `2`

**user_follower**

```
user_id | follower_id
-----------------
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 3
```

**User**

```
id | name
---------------
1 | Kuldeep
2 | john
3 | Jacob
```

I need an `sql query` all the information of user `1` followers along with thier followers count so the expected result for user `1` would be

```
id name count
2  john  1
3  jacob 0
```

I am using `PHP with mysql` so whatever is the optmial way of doing it is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join of the `user_follower` table to construct the relationships, followed by a join to the `User` table to obtain the names will give you the result you want:

```
SELECT uf1.follower_id AS id, u.name, COUNT(uf2.follower_id) AS count
FROM user_follower uf1
    LEFT JOIN user_follower uf2
        ON uf1.follower_id = uf2.user_id
    INNER JOIN User u
        ON uf1.follower_id = u.id
WHERE uf1.user_id = 1
GROUP BY uf1.follower_id
```

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66d498/4)

Comment: Thank you so much, its working , just being curious can you look at @
AnkiiG answer before I mark it as an answer, I am not a DB expert so just looking for the optimal answer

Comment: You need the self join because you are trying to get followers count for a given user's followers.  Conceptually, this is like building a graph from a user to a follower, and then from each follower to its followers.  The second step requires the join.

Comment: will this query also work if I want user `following` me instead of follower by just changing the `where clause`?

Comment: I need to find all users following user `1` along with their followers count

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
select id,name,count(user_follower.user_id) as count 
from user 
left join user_follower 
on user.id = user_follower.user_id 
group by user.id
```

Check [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9628f/1/0)

Comment: I am not getting the desired result from your query, @Tim Biegeleisen answer is resulting in what I am looking for, still I am curious how could it be done without using a self join as used by Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the self join of the `user_follower` table.  Actually, the self join is the backbone of the query.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your comments :)

Comment: @AnkiiG Your answer won't work, as op needs id, name, followers count of followers of user 1 .. (one step deeper), which can be achieved by subquery or self join.